# How to concatenate multiple variable and strings in functions in jquery

Tags: jquery

This seems like it should be simple, so not sure what i'm missing

```
// this works
$("#Q270_1, #Q271_1").change(function () {
    alert("Check 1")
});

// this works
var m1c1 = "#Q270";
$(m1c1+"_1").change(function () {
    alert("Check 2")
});

// This doesn't work
var m1c2 = "#Q271";
$(m1c1+"_1",m1c2+"_1").change(function () {
    alert("Check 3")
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle where it shows the above:
https://jsfiddle.net/9Led5cv9/

Any assistance much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to include the `,` within the quotes, as it's part of the selector string. Additionally, you need to concatenate the m1c2 with a `+`. `$(m1c1+"_1,"+m1c2+"_1")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating 2 parameters which jQuery interprets as:

```
$(selector, context)
```

This would be the same as `$(context).find(selector)`

You need to concatenate the full string instead keeping the comma inside quotes

```
$(m1c1+ "_1, " + m1c2+"_1")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, there I go not understanding the basics! 
Updated fiddle with if anyone else comes across this issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/9Led5cv9/3/

Comment: even simpler is give those elements a common class. Will make it easier reading the code later on

Answer (score 0):

stringify that comma:

```
$(m1c1+"_1, "+m1c2+"_1").change(function () {
    alert("Check 3")
});
```

Now the 1 argument references both elements.

Note: I'd give the elements a class, instead of generating long complicated lists of jQuery selectors.